# Flipping Origins of Axes 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

This is the code I am using:

```
Plot3D[MainLogisticSolution[.23, 0, t, initialpopsize], {t, 0, 
  200}, {Q, 0, 1000}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t (days)", "Q (cms)", "n (population size)"}]
```

To produce this plot:

[image: 3D Plot- flood effects on pop. size over time]

However, I am wondering how I can get the origins for the axes to flip... In particular, I would like the 'Q' axis origin to be flip-flopped, as well as the 'time' axis.  Thanks much.

Comment: I think you've just rotated the plot to make it look like that. Try rotating it 180 degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by "_flip-flopped_"?

Answer (score 1):

```
plot =
 Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Q", "n"}]
```

[image]

Now use `Rotate`to flip the Q-axis

```
Graphics3D[
 Rotate[First@plot, Pi, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "Q", "n"}]
```

[image]

You can also use `Viewpoint` to look at different perspectives

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "Q", "n"},
 ViewPoint -> {Front, Left}]
```

[image]